# Decrypt data encrypted with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt, ccavenue

CCAvenue uses MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 to encrypt transaction data. Since my server is running PHP 7.1, Im unable to decrypt this data.

Is there any workaround to decrypt this string on PHP 7.1 or Do I have to downgrade to PHP 5 to get this working.

Decryption code from ccavenue

```
    function decrypt($encryptedText,$key)
    {
        $secretKey = hextobin(md5($key));
        $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
        $encryptedText=hextobin($encryptedText);
        $openMode = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '','cbc', '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($openMode, $secretKey, $initVector);
        $decryptedText = mdecrypt_generic($openMode, $encryptedText);
        $decryptedText = rtrim($decryptedText, "\0");
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($openMode);
        return $decryptedText;

    }
```

Response on decryption

```
Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()
```

Comment: http://helpdoc.info/mcrypt_rijndael_128-is-not-working-with-php-7-x-with-ccavenue/

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Turns our CCAvenue has pushed a PHP 7.1 compatible version.

Open SSL Compatible version of code

```
function encrypt($plainText,$key)
{
  $key = hextobin(md5($key));
  $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
  $openMode = openssl_encrypt($plainText, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $initVector);
  $encryptedText = bin2hex($openMode);
  return $encryptedText;
}

function decrypt($encryptedText,$key)
{
  $key = hextobin(md5($key));
  $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
  $encryptedText = hextobin($encryptedText);
  $decryptedText = openssl_decrypt($encryptedText, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $initVector);
  return $decryptedText;

}
```

Comment: Where did you see this code pushed? I'm using this repo and don't see any such updates: https://github.com/kishanio/CCAvenue-PHP-Library/

Comment: Note: `hextobin` should be `hex2bin` http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Comment: Correction: `hextobin` should be `$this->hextobin` or use PHPs `hex2bin` http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Comment: Yea the code is not available in any repo , Had to contact support to get code

Answer (score 0):

Try using openssl_encrypt($input, 'AES-128-CBC', "KEY", OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

Comment: Tried. I get a response as false

Comment: mcrypt is deprecated in php7.1 but i think it is not yet removed.

Comment: Nope. i get "Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()

" error

Comment: Did you installed and enabled mcrypt in

Comment: Not keen on installing a depreciated library on my new project. If all fails, tat would be last option